# Trying ubuntu newest version via bootable usb works fine, but installing it and booting makes it stay on purple screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb

I had some problems with windows and I decided to try Ubuntu. 
I have an msi laptop with nvidia drivers and intel core i7.

I put in the bootable Usb and I make it boot option 1 in Bios. I get 4 options, I chose the first one "Try Ubuntu"

I go in it works all fine and I decide to install Ubuntu via the install exe. on the desktop. I install it but i don't check "install third party software" box. It installs all fine, and I manually shut the PC down and then go into bios and make USB boot 2nd and Ubuntu Hard drive 1st boot option.

I choose the first option in the grub menu called Ubuntu, and it just goes in to a blank purple screen. I Can not use the ctrl alt f1 or all those commands.

If I make USB boot option 1 it works fine, but it is just a trial and not the full installed Ubuntu.

I am not advanced when it comes to things that include terminal and codes and such, so you might call me a novice, but I know my way around all the basic controls like control panel on windows and fixing simple problems.

Any help would be appreciated since I really am a novice at Ubuntu.

Have a nice day!

Greetings from Denmark

Comment: you need the third party software that it offers to install

Comment: Ok bro! I will try that! )